# Search specific code on an entire website

Tags: html, search

I want to search a specific site for a code snippet, for example `<a href=tel:`

Is there a way to do this in a search engine, browser plugin or other way?

Comment: [STRG] + F ?? Or What do you mean?

Comment: use: `site:example.com "search keyword"` E.g. `site:wikipedia.com "english"`

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Comment: What´s wrong with you guys. Are you really such buffoons? I think this question is clear and legitimate. If the site has many many pages you can't use just google or Crtl-F to find a string in the source code on some page.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome developer tools let you do that (not sure about how other debuggers handle it).

Open the developer tools (F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+J), and hit ESC. In the mini console that's opened at the bottom, go to the Search tab. It will search all of the resources (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, sources from maps, etc).

If you're referring to something someone wrote on the page (rather than it being in the source code), your best bet is to use a search engine and query like `site:example.com "search keywords here"`.

Answer (score -2):

This is not the right place to ask....

If you are using Google Chrome, `Right Click` then hit `Inspect element` Press `Ctrl` and `F`, you will see a text box. Type to search the html code you wanted at there!

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to search a complete site(all of its pages) in Google after a searchstring eg. {<a href=tel:} not go into each website and all of it's pages.

Comment: Not impossible. Difficult maybe but httrack could be used to download the entire site and then a file searcher used to search the downloaded directory. I know that's overkill and extremely time consuming but not impossible.